# Identify the WiFi

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, wifi

I install elementary os on Lenovo Ideapad Y700.
the laptop run before with win 10 and every thing work fine.
after installing elementary os the system doesn't identify the WiFi but its let me to connect with wire connection.

whats i'm doing wrong or how can i define my wifi?

I used elementary os on old lenvovo laptop and it's identify the WiFi automatically with no problem.

**the spec of the computer:**
Processor---------6th Generation Intel® Quad-Core i7 Processor
Discrete Graphics---------NVIDIA® GTX 960M 4 GB GDDR5
Memory---------16 GB DDR4
Webcam---------HD 720p, 2 x Internal Digital Array Microphone, or Intel 3D RealSense Camera (Optional)

Storage --------- 128 ssd with 1 TB HDD 
Audio--------- 2 x 2W JBL Speakers with Chamber + 3.0 W Subwoofer and Dolby® Home Theater™
Battery ---------  4 Cell 60 WHr
Keyboard--------- Red LED Backlit with 2 Level Brightness Control
Display --------- Frameless Full HD (1920 x 1080) or Ultra HD (3840 x 2160) 16:9 IPS Anti-Glare
Dimensions

```
(inches) : 15.23" x 10.90" x 1.02"
(mm) : 387 x 277 x 25.95
```

ODD--------- Optional External USB 2.0 DVD/BD Tray-In

**WLAN--------- LAN 1000 M, Up to WiFi 2 x 2 a/c + Bluetooth® 4.0**
Ports--------- 2 x USB 3.0, 1 x USB 2.0 + Always-on, DC-in, 2-in-1 Audio Combo Jack, 1 x HDMI, 1 x 4-in-1 Media Card Reader (SD, SDHC, SDXC, MMC)

Answer (score 1):

The elementary kernel doesn't have the correct (new) drivers for Skylake (6th gen. ix) machines. On the other hand the newest kernels gave me other glitches / incompatibilities with elementary. 
Kernel 4.2.8 and following ckt versions do the job for me.
Intel graphics then still also need some tweaking:
You should add **i915.preliminary_hw_support=1** to grub to get hardware accelleration from the Intel GPU as well.
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=intel-skl-prelim-support

Google "elementary OS Skylake" for all info on the broader subject.
I run elementary OS on an Intel NUC6i3 (also Skylake) and also had to work through these issues. Everything runs super stable and snappy fast now.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, every time I turn on elementary OS (or any other Linux distribution) I can't connect to Wifi, but when I put it on sleep then turn it on again, it connects to Wifi then. Try first that, and if it doesn't work, try Alex's method.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the answers.
I use this solution for my problem and it's work well http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2016/05/fixing-linux-mint-wireless-issues-on.html

Now I have anther issues with my graphic card and some reboot problems like after reboot I get black screen or after update when i press restart the system freeze